# navigation stack get crash

Tags: navigation, costmap, clear-costmap, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working with the navigation stack and when I command a goal (by rviz) which is inside an obstacle I get the following error. This is something I have begun to experience recently (after upgrading some Ros packages).

If you need any configuration file, I can provide them.

```
[ WARN] [1413287442.128433137, 500.284000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 1.0820 seconds
[ WARN] [1413287447.391084978, 502.616000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 2.1320 seconds
[ WARN] [1413287450.041637304, 503.840000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 1.2240 seconds
[ WARN] [1413287452.804671449, 505.062000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 1.0220 seconds
[ WARN] [1413287452.835355243, 505.075000000]: Clearing costmap to unstuck robot.

[move_base-3] process has died [pid 16397, exit code -11, cmd /home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/move_base/move_base odom:=odometry/filtered hokuyo_laser_topic:=scan cmd_vel:=/summit_xl_robot_control/command __name:=move_base __log:=/home/summitxl/.ros/log/3bb2ad12-5396-11e4-ac48-9cb70d1c3f04/move_base-3.log].
log file: /home/summitxl/.ros/log/3bb2ad12-5396-11e4-ac48-9cb70d1c3f04/move_base-3*.log
```

Thank you

My debug output is here:
https://gist.github.com/arenillas/2408efc78094d1a0be24

EDIT:

Using the parameter default_tolerance (5 meters) the result is:

```
[ WARN] [1414505173.888202638, 61.526000000]: Map update loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz... the loop actually took 0.7650 seconds
[ WARN] [1414505173.930135630, 61.537000000]: Invalid Trajectory 0.000000, 0.000000, -0.400000, cost: -1.000000
```

And after some time and repetitions of these two warnings:

```
[ WARN] [1414505212.929234900, 71.937000000]: Clearing costmap to unstuck robot.
[move_base-3] process has died [pid 3922, exit code -11, cmd /home/summitxl/ros_catkin_ws/install_isolated/lib/move_base/move_base odom:=odometry/filtered hokuyo_laser_topic:=scan cmd_vel:=/summit_xl_robot_control/command __name:=move_base __log:=/home/summitxl/.ros/log/24466806-5eab-11e4-bdf7-047d7b44770f/move_base-3.log].
log file: /home/summitxl/.ros/log/24466806-5eab-11e4-bdf7-047d7b44770f/move_base-3*.log
```

EDIT:

Finally, it was a problem in costmap package. It has been fixed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194936/navigation-stack-get-crash/) by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 223 on 2014-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2014-10-14**:
Looks like a core dump and shouldn't happen. Do you use any non-standard plugins?

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-14**:
I don't think so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're running a source-built version of navigation, I assume there's a good reason to not use debs?

First step for diagnosing would be to set the log level to debug for move_base and post that output as well.

---

EDIT: From the log file, you're having an error where the observations (i.e. laserscan ray endpoints or pointcloud) received by the [obstacle layer](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Computing+map+coords+failed) of your map are not within the costmap bounds. This is probably a misconfiguration somewhere, either with your map size (maybe your static map which overrides your map size), or your tf transforms.

Since you're already building navigation from source, I would recommend hooking it up to a debugger, or just adding some additional ROS_DEBUGs in the problem area to try to figure out where the calculations are going wrong.

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-14**:
I am using source version because the project has to be developed in Ubuntu 13.10 and ros hydro is not available in it.

Can you explain how to set log lever to debug??

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-15**:
http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Logging - > http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_logger_level

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-21**:
Can I send you the file to your email?
It is huge and I do not know where to look

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-27**:
Now I know the problem is in the global map.
Whenever I command a goal that is inside inflation layer of the obstacles, it crashes

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-27**:
I imagine that it is possible to set a goal like that. Am I wrong?
I suppose that in that case the move_base should warn you with a message like "unreachable goal", but not crashing. Am I right?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-27**:
Try raising the the default tolerance parameter on the global planner.

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-27**:
Are you sure that I can command a goal like this?

http://postimg.org/image/3t9we94kv/

In that case, what should happen when the robot is not able to get there because it is inside an obstacle?

Thank you

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-27**:
Taking a look at the [code](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/b384cac812381a9313d7cdc9be9eb272c4fccb38/navfn/src/navfn_ros.cpp#L296), the global planner will try to find the closest legal point using the default_tolerance parameter as a limit.

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-28**:
I have tried it but the problem continues appearing when the clearing. What's that?

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-10-28**:
Sorry, I have no idea. At this point, it sounds like a regression issue (move_base shouldn't be core dumping either way), perhaps you could open a ticket for it in https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation, along with full details of your configuration, steps to reproduce, etc.

**Comment by [arenillas](https://answers.ros.org/users/15376/arenillas/) on 2014-10-29**:
Thank you for all your help.
As you said, it was an issue (divide by zero) and it has been already fixed.